# Overriding issues in Scala

Tags: scala

I will let the code speak:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait SomeRequest
trait SomeResponse
trait ApiStandard {
  def apiCall[Req <: SomeRequest, Resp <: SomeResponse](request: Req): Future[Resp]
}

case class XXRequest() extends SomeRequest
case class XXResponse() extends SomeResponse
class XXStandard extends ApiStandard {
  override def apiCall(request: XXRequest): Future[XXResponse] = ???
}
```

Basically I have a couple of data traits (SomeRequest, SomeResponse) and a behaviour trait ApiStandard. There are also case classes XXRequest and XXResponse which override the data traits. I am trying to create a concrete implementation of of ApiStandard called XXStandard. But it's not syntactically correct. Being a Scala beginner, I can't understand why.

Please throw some light.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

ApiStandard defines a method `apiCall` that accepts a parameter that is more flexible than what `XXStandard` provides.

To illustrate,

If you have

```
val something: ApiStandard = ???
```

you know you can call

```
val req: SomeRequest
something(req)
```

If the `???` would be able to be `new XXStandard()`, and `XXStandard` only accepts `XXRequest`s as it's argument to apiCall, this would be broken: there is no way to know req is in fact an `XXRequest`, and indeed, it doesn't have to be one.

Furtunately, this doesn't compile, because `apiCall` in `XXStandard` can't implement `ApiStandard.apiCall`.

To make `XXStandard` into something that can be a subtype of ApiStandard, apiCall in XXStandard has to take a type that is what you declared in your trait, or a supertype of that as its argument.

tl;dr:

Methods are contravariant in their parameter type.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn. Could you please explain how could I rewrite this?

Comment: Not in a comment or a single answer here. Tangentially related, https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html is a good read.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martijn for giving reference to that article. Will definitely read it.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `apiCall` says it must work for any `Req <: SomeRequest` and `Resp <: SomeResponse`, so the caller can call it like (e.g.) `apiCall[MyReq, SomeoneElsesResp](new MyReq)`. But the implementation in `XXStandard` doesn't work like this; it only supports a single request and response type. Assuming that's what you wanted, you need to move type arguments to `ApiStandard`:

```
trait ApiStandard[Req <: SomeRequest, Resp <: SomeResponse] {
  def apiCall(request: Req): Future[Resp]
}

class XXStandard extends ApiStandard[XXRequest, XXResponse] {
  override def apiCall(request: XXRequest): Future[XXResponse] = ???
}
```

Comment: You may want to upvote the reply in this case (and accept this or Martijn's reply).

Comment: My apologies for the bad etiquettes. I just upvoted. Thanks again.